# Application Pool Identity Predefined/Configurable switch with Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-6, windows-server-2003, application-pool

I'm writing a PowerShell script to set a UserName and Password on Identity settings in Application Pool on IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003 R2). For that purposes i'm using vbscript from  [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f05a7c2b-36b0-4b6e-ac7c-662700081f25.mspx?mfr=true). But after running a script i still have to manually switch "Identity" from "Predefined" to "Configurable". Is there a way to select "Configurable" via powershell script?

[image]

Comment: If you're writing a PowerShell script, why is your question tagged "VBScript"? Also, please show your code.

Comment: because to set password/username i use servers vb scripts. And it's easy to launch vbscripts from powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution. The following PowerShell code solves the issue.

```
#Assigning Identity's Username To AppPool    
cscript adsutil.vbs SET w3svc/AppPools/YourAppPoolName/WAMUserName Username

#Assigning Identity's Password To AppPool
cscript adsutil.vbs SET w3svc/AppPools/YourAppPoolName/WAMUserPass Password

#Making ApplicationPool Configurable
cscript adsutil.vbs SET w3svc/AppPools/YourAppPoolName/AppPoolIdentityType 3
```